# Is travel to Iraqi Kurdistan without an Iraqi visa a problem when applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-residents, iraqi-kurdistan

I will soon be making a UK visa application to extend a temporary stay in the UK.

Iraqi Kurdistan gives nationals of most Western countries [visa-free access](https://us.gov.krd/en/services/visa-information/). However, there is an ongoing dispute between the Iraqi and Iraqi-Kurdish government over whether they are allowed to do this.

The [UK Foreign Commonwealth Office](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/iraq) says that all nationals need an Iraqi federal visa to enter any part of Iraq, including Iraqi Kurdistan:

> According to Iraqi law you must have a visa before you travel, even if
>   you’re intending to travel to the Kurdistan Region of Iraq.

Is entering Iraqi Kurdistan visa-free a potential problem for being granted a UK visa, given that the British government apparently views such an entry as unlawful (and thus as a violation of a foreign immigration law)?